# The constructor of an API controller never gets called in my Blazor project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I am new to Blazor and I created an API Controller to handle my CRUD routines.  It has a constructor so I can save the connection to the database to a private member.  However, when my app starts up, the constructor never gets called.  I also have tried to send the controller a POST, I get a bad request so I am assuming that its still not setup correctly.  Thank you for your help!

**StartUp.cs**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
      }
      else
      {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios,
        // see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
      }

      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseStaticFiles();

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
      });

    }
```

**PTSEventController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ComEd.PTS.DataStore.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ComEd.PTS.Event.UI.Controllers
{
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class PTSEventController : ControllerBase
  {
    private readonly PeakTimeSavingsDBContext _dbContext;

    public PTSEventController(PeakTimeSavingsDBContext dbContext)
    {
      _dbContext = dbContext; //<<<< The constructor never gets called >>>>
    }

    // GET: api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
      return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
      return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
      int x = 0;
      x++;
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
      int x = 0;
      x++;

    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
      int x = 0;
      x++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess your controller is not within a Web Api, right ? I would suggest you create a Web Api  project in the same solution in which your server-side blazor resides. Or create a service instead. Could you please post the content of the ConfigureServices method.

Comment: Can we see the .razor code that is trying to call "api/PTSEvent" ?

Comment: Hey, I got it to work.  I assumed that when the app starts up the constructor for the controller would get called but it doesn't.  It doesn't happen until you a GET or POST to it.  My problem was I was not using the correct URI for the controller.  The correct URL was https://localhost:44306/api/ptsevent/1 and not https://localhost:44306/api/ptseventcontroller/1.  My bad.  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Classic (getting the URL wrong) ;) Adding Swagger to the project is often a good idea - then U can browser the API along with easy-to-use examples of how to call the different functions on the controllers ect. Takes a little to learn, but (imho) SUPER well worth the time/effort

Answer (score 0):

Add your class as a service?

in ConfigureServices() in startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<PTSEventController>();
```